# Multiple Insert in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have these forms which are composed of more than 15 (approximately) textfields which would likely be inserted on 4 different tables in the DB. Just so you know, I am still using the MySQL without `i` because I am still not adept to it. I run down this code in PHP&MySQL which totally not working...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee (name,birthday,pob,gender,civil,email,contact,address,paddress,citizenship)
VALUES ($name,$date,$bplace,$gender,$civil,$email,$contact,$address,$postcode,$citizenship)") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO education (elementary,egrad,highschool,hgrad,vocational,vgrad)
VALUES ($elem,$edate,$high,$hdate,$voc,$vdate)") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO employment_history (workOne,estartDate,eendDate,workTwo,wstartDate,wendDate,workThree,hstartDate,hendDate)
VALUES ($erw,$erdate,$end,$wrw,$wrdate,$wend,$hrw,$hstart,$hend)") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO referrence (refA,refAcc,refAdd,refB,refBcc,refBdd,refC,refCcc,refCdd)
VALUES ($refOne,$refOnedd,$refOnecc,$refTwo,$refTwoadd,$refTwocc,$refThree,$refThreeadd,$refThreecc)") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');
```

The codes above are the sample attribute s(somewhat similar) with the DB am using. I don't know what went wrong, but I suppose that am doing the right thing. Am I wrong?

And btw, I've also tried the MySQLi before, but the values couldn't be easily retrieved... I guess the `mysqli_fetched_assoc();` has something sensitive around it. Like data couldn't be merged under `<table>` the way I did with `mysql_fetch_array();`

Here's what I did on `MySQLi`
Figure 2:

```
 $query= "INSERT INTO employee (name,birthday,pob,gender,civil,email,contact,address,paddress,citizenship)
 VALUES ($name,$date,$bplace,$gender,$civil,$email,$contact,$address,$postcode,$citizenship)";

 $query.= "INSERT INTO education (elementary,egrad,highschool,hgrad,vocational,vgrad)
 VALUES ($elem,$edate,$high,$hdate,$voc,$vdate)";

 $query.= "INSERT INTO employment_history (workOne,estartDate,eendDate,workTwo,wstartDate,wendDate,workThree,hstartDate,hendDate)
 VALUES ($erw,$erdate,$end,$wrw,$wrdate,$wend,$hrw,$hstart,$hend)";

 $query.= "INSERT INTO referrence (refA,refAcc,refAdd,refB,refBcc,refBdd,refC,refCcc,refCdd)
 VALUES ($refOne,$refOnedd,$refOnecc,$refTwo,$refTwoadd,$refTwocc,$refThree,$refThreeadd,$refThreecc)";

/* execute multi query */
if (mysqli_multi_query($link,$query)) {
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    /* print divider */
    if (mysqli_more_results($link)) {
        printf("-----------------\n");
    }
} while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```

Comment: You need single quotes around you string values,assuming they are not int

Comment: Also, I'll suggest that you use a stored procedure instead.

Comment: If you want to write queries so neat without any need of quotation marks and to escape the data, move to prepared statements and abandon `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Just don't do that. Even if you can get it to work, you'll be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @AlexTrebek but when I tried the Figure 2, nothing did save.

Comment: Your second example is a single query with syntax errors. You need to separate the queries with semicolons: `;`.

Comment: And you still need quotes around your variables, as suggested, or use prepared statements (which would be a better choice).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider but it has semicolons at the end of each statements. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @Archangel08 You have semicolons that end the PHP command. You have no semicolons inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose data in `VALUES(` in quotes `''` . Your code should look like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO employee (name,birthday,pob,gender,civil,email,contact,address,paddress,citizenship)
VALUES ('$name','$date','$bplace','$gender','$civil','$email','$contact','$address','$postcode','$citizenship')") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO education (elementary,egrad,highschool,hgrad,vocational,vgrad)
VALUES ('$elem','$edate','$high','$hdate','$voc','$vdate')") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO employment_history (workOne,estartDate,eendDate,workTwo,wstartDate,wendDate,workThree,hstartDate,hendDate)
VALUES ('$erw','$erdate','$end','$wrw','$wrdate','$wend','$hrw','$hstart','$hend')") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO referrence (refA,refAcc,refAdd,refB,refBcc,refBdd,refC,refCcc,refCdd)
VALUES ('$refOne','$refOnedd','$refOnecc','$refTwo','$refTwoadd','$refTwocc','$refThree','$refThreeadd',$refThreecc')") or die('Access denied or can\'t find database');
```

One advice for you, you should not use mysql_* function because it is deprecated. I hope this helps you

Comment: You should not advise to use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I have not advised him to use mysql_* function but i corrected his error

Comment: @Utkarsh thanks for your help... by the way... I'm a girl.. :P ;)

Comment: @Archangel08 Sorry i didn't knew that

Comment: @Utkarsh, its okay, Sir.
and as for the code you provided, neither it nor the mysqli have worked so far.